# App Using Way More RAM Than It Should

Tags: ios, firebase, sprite-kit, admob, xcode8

I'm working on a iOS project and I recently started messing around with AdMob for in-game ads.

Ever since I installed the `pods` and `firebase` stuff, my `RAM` usage has been through the roof.

I've seen it go as high as `600MB` on startup. My app, with all images (`@1x`, `@2x`, and `@3x` sizes) is only about `75MB`.

I even created a new project and copied the source/scene files into it to have a fresh start without the `AdMob`/`Firebase` stuff in it and even removed all my images from the `asset` catalog, but I'm still hitting `200MB`+ on my `RAM` usage.

Sometimes the app crashes due to memory usage just on startup because of this.

Has anyone run into this issue or know what I can try to do to fix it?

Comment: It is really hard to know why your memory is building up without seeing your actual code. Also, you should really use Instruments and check for memory leaks and usage there to get a hint of what causes your memory to hit so hard. Another suggestion is to simply read other threads about this: https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=admob+memory+leak+ios&* finally. It would be helpful for people to know what else you have tried other than just creating a new project, if anything ?

Comment: I used instruments to check for leaks, and it only came back with leaks that were in the 100's of bytes. There's not a whole lot to my code and it used to be in the expected 75-80MB range before installing all the AdMob stuff. Is there some Xcode setting that may have gotten changed and is saved for all projects that could cause massive memory usage? I expected all the issues to go away after creating a fresh project.

Comment: You should not have leaks at all, so my suggestion is you try to allocate the problem and solve that part first. Second you should check the link with the other threads with simliar issues and the different solutions and suggested there to the same issue. Thats all I can suggest for now. Maybe you could update your question with your findings and someone else could help you reach even deeper and find the solution hopefully if you didn't already by then. GL